# keycloak group members causes LDAP query for each individual user

Tags: keycloak

I have a keycloak instance with a read only LDAP Federation. I add members to groups by searching for both GROUP_ID and USER_ID (which queries the LDAP server) and then using a 'PUT' to add the USER to the GROUP (I use python to parse the JSON):

```
GROUP_ID=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/groups|python -c '
import json,sys,os;keycloak_data=json.load(sys.stdin);
GROUP=os.environ["GROUP"]
for g in keycloak_data:
    if g["name"]==GROUP:
        print g["id"]
        sys.exit()
')


USER_ID=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/users?username=$USER | python -c '
import json,sys,os;keycloak_data=json.load(sys.stdin)
USERID=os.environ["USER"]
for c in keycloak_data:
    if c["attributes"]["LDAP_ID"][0]==USERID:
        print c["id"]
        sys.exit()
')

echo "Adding $USER to $GROUP    GROUP_ID=$GROUP_ID      USER_ID=$USER_ID"

curl -s -X PUT -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/users/$USER_ID/groups/$GROUP_ID
```

Above works great.  But when I want to get a list of the members in that group it queries LDAP for every user (which can take a long time if there are over 100 users in a group)

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/groups/$GROUP_ID/members
```

Any way to query the group membership without triggering an LDAP query for every member of the group?  I have already tried changing the LDAP Cache settings under the LDAP Federation and doesn't seem to help.

I just want to know (quickly) which users are in a given keycloak group.

Comment: Better Solution you should import the user from ldap to keycloak db and it keycloak support this feature.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I do not understand your suggestion. I opened the H2 Server and connected to the internal Keycloak DB and find the Users in the 'USER_ENTITY' table.  I also find the group memberships for each userID in the 'USER_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP' table.   I want to use the API to query that 'USER_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP' table without queries to LDAP.  I can do what I want with SQL, if the H2 embedded DB is not locked.

Comment: Why Ldap will come into the picture when user already available or import from ldap to keycloak db ?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi That is my question...The Keycloak process should not repull the LDAP info in my opionion unless a setting would to tell it to. I tried to play with the SYNC settings (eg. SYNC once a day) but did not help.  I even tried to look at the keycloak source but I am not a Java programmer and got lost in the objects.

Comment: Are you sure your Keycloak+Ldap integration working fine ?  If yes try to Sync the users it will show the notification top of the page how many user Sync/updated from ldap to Keycloak server DB.